# SQL SELECT query, tables with no column in common

Tags: mysql, sql, select, delete-row

I'm working with two databases:
The relation between the two tables is that `db1.tab1.model_id=db2.tab2.ID_ELEMENT`

```
DELETE FROM db1.tab1
WHERE db1.tab1.model_id in (
    SELECT db1.tab1.model_id 
    FROM db1.tab1
    WHERE db1.tab1.model_id = db2.tab2.ID_ELEMENT in (
        SELECT db2.tab2.ID_ELEMENT
        FROM db2.tab2
        WHERE db2.tab2.DELETED='1'
    )
);
```

I'm not very surprised this doesn't work since my 4th line sucks, but the thing is that I know I can't put

```
WHERE db1.tab1.model_id in (SELECT db2.tab2.ID_ELEMENT .....)`
```

I mean the `WHERE` clause should be the same as the `in SELECT`!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this query?
By looking at your query it seems you want to delete all the records from tab1 where it is marked as deleted in tab2.

```
DELETE db1.tab1
FROM db1.tab1 
    JOIN db2.tab2 ON db1.tab1.model_id = db2.tab2.ID_ELEMENT 
WHERE db2.tab2.DELETED='1';
```